# Data pivot in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, oracle12c

I have data like this:

```
| ITEM_CD |  CARACT_CD |   CARACT_VALUE     | DESCRIPTION |
|   1     |   A1       |   yyy              | descr1      |  
|   1     |   B1       |   xxx              | descr2      |  
|   2     |   A1       |   uuu              |             |  
|   2     |   B1       |   rrr              | descr3      |  
|   3     |   C1       |   kkk              |             |
```

I would like to have the data represented as:

```
| ITEM_CD |    A1      |   A1_DS     |    B1    |    B1_DS       |    C1    |    C1_DS       | 
|   1     |   yyy      |   descr1    |    xxx   |    descr2      |          |                |  
|   2     |   uuu      |             |    rrr   |    descr3      |          |                |  
|   3     |            |             |          |                |    kkk   |                |
```

Can someone please help me to write the correct query using the PIVOT function in Oracle ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: May help: https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-pivot/

Answer (score 1):

I recommend conditional aggregation:

```
select item_cd,
       max(case when CARACT_CD = 'A1' then CARACT_VALUE end) as a1,
       max(case when CARACT_CD = 'A1' then DESCRIPTION end) as a1_desc,
       max(case when CARACT_CD = 'B1' then CARACT_VALUE end) as b1,
       max(case when CARACT_CD = 'B1' then DESCRIPTION end) as b1_desc,
       max(case when CARACT_CD = 'C1' then CARACT_VALUE end) as c1,
       max(case when CARACT_CD = 'C1' then DESCRIPTION end) as c1_desc
from t
group by item_cd;
```

I don't recommend `pivot`.  Conditional aggregation can do everything it does -- and much more -- with similar or better performance.

Comment: Thank you for your help (and the update of my request). I'll follow your advice.